# Equilibrium concentration of point defects in solids at sufficiently elevated temperature

Tags: materials

Equilibrium concentration of point defects in solids is defined as $\chi=\exp(\frac{\Delta s}{k_B})\exp(\frac{-\Delta h}{k_BT})$. At high temperatures, may be even higher than melting temperature of the solid, does the entropy become undefined meaning there will be no equilibrium concentration for point defects?

Comment: Have you considered the chemistry stack?

Comment: The concept of 'point defect' is already meaningless, when the material is in liquid phase.